# Add Mass action to grid via observer

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, massaction

I'd like to add mass action column in CMS->Blocks only via observer, and not to overwrite blocks.. ok, so far I have this:

[image]

code:

I'm targeting this event:

```
<events>
  <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    <observers>
      <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before_handler>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>masspages/observer</class>
        <method>addMassAction</method>
        <args></args>
      </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before_handler>
    </observers>
  </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
</events>
```

and observer code for test col is:

```
public function addMassAction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Grid) {

        $block->addColumn('block_id', array(
            'header' => 'My title',
            'index' => 'block_id',
        ));
    }
}
```

}

I have tried to put function _prepareMassaction() somewhere,, but how to call it makes me puzzled??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are on the right track :)

Firstly, use the event `adminhtml_block_html_before` instead of `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before_handler`

Then in your observer you can add this code to get a mass action added:

```
public function adminhtml_block_html_before($event) {

    $block = $event->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Grid) {


        $block->setMassactionIdField('block_id');
        $block->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('block_ids');
        $block->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        $block->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('YOUR_MASS_ACTION_ITEM_NAME', array(
            'label' => 'YOUR LABEL',
            'url' => $block->getUrl('*/*/YOUR CONTROLLERACTION'),
        ));

        $columnId = 'massaction';

        $massactionColumn = array(
            'index' => $block->getMassactionIdField(),
            'filter_index' => $block->getMassactionIdFilter(),
            'type' => 'massaction',
            'name' => $block->getMassactionBlock()->getFormFieldName(),
            'align' => 'center',
            'is_system' => true
        );

        if ($block->getNoFilterMassactionColumn()) {
            $massactionColumn->setData('filter', false);
        }

        // rearrange the columns;
        $oldColumns = $block->getColumns();
        foreach($oldColumns as $column){
           $block->removeColumn($column->getId());  
        }

        $block->addColumn($columnId, $massactionColumn);
        $block->addColumn('block_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('ID'),
            'width' => '50px',
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'block_id',
        ));

        // put back the original columns
        foreach($oldColumns as $column){
            $block->addColumn($column->getId(),$column->getData());
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thats great, thanks! It did add the mass action selector on top of grid, but I can't add column that would be 'binded' the items counting..? You got any more tips how to go with that..

Comment: Hi, Is there any reason you need to add the new column? If it is only to get a unique ID for the mass_action code, you don't need it. You can pass the identifier (as per my example code), which is unique per entry. You can use this then to manipulate the data.

Comment: Your $block->addColumn as per your question, should still work here. You are still manipulating the same block, just via a different event.

Comment: Yes, I have entered correct identifier, in my case for CMS->BLock it is 'block_id', but on magento 1.7 the column is not rendered but on magento 1.4 all cool and working great! here,, this column: http://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/massaction_grid.png

Comment: Ok, gotcha - I updated the answer with new code which ads in the massaction column. :)

Comment: Great!, now all works like rocket... thank you very much ProxiBlue!

Comment: How to remove an item from massaction list?